# Harvard CS50P PSET 4: timed out while waiting for program to exit

Tags: python, cs50

I'm solving [this problem](https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022/psets/4/professor/).

My code works when I test it but it is failing the provided check with the error:

> :( Little Professor accepts valid level // timed out while waiting for program to exit

It passes the three previous checks for invalid levels. Any insight to why this might be happening would help.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    level = get_level()
    q=1
    s=0
    while q<=10:
        try:
            x = generate_integer(level)
            y = generate_integer(level)
            ans = x + y
            eq = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
        
            if ans == eq:
                s += 1
                pass
            
            elif ans != eq:
                c = 1
                while c <= 2:
                    print('EEE')
                    eq = int(input(f'{x} + {y} = '))
                    
                    if ans == eq:
                        s += 1
                        break

                    else:
                        c += 1
                        
                if c == 3:
                    print('EEE')
                    print(f'{x} + {y} = {ans}')
            q += 1
            
        except EOFError:
            pass
        
    print(f'Score: {s}')
    
def get_level(): 
    valid_inputs = (1,2,3)
    while True:
        try:
            level = int(input('Level: '))
            if level in valid_inputs:
                return level
            else:
                pass
        except ValueError:
            pass
        

def generate_integer(level):
    max = 10**level-1
    min = 10**(level-1)
    
    if level == 1:
        min == 0
    
    num = random.randint(min,max)
    
    return num

main()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your program (as-is) and found at least 1 problem. I'm not sure if it's why `check50` flags that error, but you will need to fix it before it will pass. I entered `Level: 1`, then got a duplicate equation (`4 + 5 =` ). This violates a requirement buried under **How to Test**: "*Your program should output **10 distinct** problems*" (emphasis mine). It's easy to miss - I didn't see it until someone mentioned it on the CS50P ED Forum.

Also, the last 2 lines of your program are supposed to be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Instead, only you have:

```
main()
```

Finally, this is an observation on your code structure. You have a lot of `if` statements for the 3 attempts to answer the question. It's overly complicated and kind of hard to follow. Hint: It can be simplified with another loop to prompt and check answers.